# How to read AWS CLI command responses

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, command-line

When I run AWS SDK command line in Powershell to, for example, get the instances in a Gamelift Fleet, I get visual response in the command window in the form of JSON.   Suppose I wanted to run that command in a script and parse the reply for another script.  Anybody know how I access that reply content from the command window?

As in, a sequence of powershell commands in a script:  run line 1  CLI command, get JSON back and read reply, pass reply to Line 2 command, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the output of a command to a variable like this:

```
$output = <AWS command>
```

After that, you can use the variable however you need to, such as passing it as a parameter in another command or parsing the data. Also, you can use the GetType() function like this `$output.GetType()` to determine exactly what type of data the command is returning since it may not be immediately clear.